# Six boxes are numbered from $1$ through $6$. How many are there to distribute $20$ identical balls in those boxes (some of the boxes may be empty)?

Tags: combinatorics

Six boxes are numbered from $1$ through $6$. How many ways are there to distribute $20$ identical balls in those boxes (some of the boxes may be empty)?

Well, my solution goes like this:

> Now, we can solve this by considering those $20 $ balls as objects and we can partition them in $5$ walls (say) such that each partition represents to a number of balls in one box.  So we have $25$ objects and we can arrange them $25!$ ways. But we have $20$ objects of same kind and $6$ objects of the other kind. So , the total no. of ways this can be arranged is $25!/20!5!$.

We can also solve this in the following way:

> We have $20$ objects . So, we have $21$ spaces for the placement of the $5$ walls and we can place this in $21\choose 5$ ways.By doing this all the $20$ objects get partitioned among the $6$ boxes considered.

However, the answer in both the cases must be same. But why are they different? Why isn't at least one of the methods valid? Where is the problem occuring? I am not quite getting it...

Comment: The second way is incorrect because you can have two (or more) walls at the same place. The first way is correct. Cf. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks! But can u please explain what do u mean by we can have more than one walls in the same place ...i mean...we  can choose any of those $5$ positions out of those $21$ positions...

Comment: Yes, but each position can be occupied by at most one wall. However, in reality you *can* have more than one wall at the same place, and you are not counting those. For example, try to represent the case where only box $2$ is empty.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks a lot! Well acvording to the 2nd method there cannot be 2 walls in the space between two objects. The condition there implies that only one wall can be placed btween any two objects space (i.e the space between two objects)...so we cannot keep two walls side by side so as to get a possible arrangement that one interior box(i.e 2nd,3rd ,4th or 5th box) empty...it misses those cases..so it is not valid, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The cases missed should be precisely those where one of the interior boxes is empty.

Comment: @StinkingBishop ...Thanks a lot! I do get it now....Thanks!

Comment: And ... thinking about that, if we only want to calculate the number of arrangements where the interior four boxes are nonempty, put one ball into them in advance, and solve the original problem with $16$ remaining balls and $6$ boxes. If you now follow the (correct) first approach, you will get $21\choose 5$, which is exactly what you got following the erroneous second approach.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Nice catch.  I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative explanation for why the 2nd line of reasoning is false :

You don't have $21$ objects.  You have $20 + 5$ objects.  The reason is that each ball is an object, and each wall is an object.  You need $(6-1)$ walls in order to create $(6)$ regions, each of which is separated by a wall.

So, the enumeration is the number of ways of selecting $[6-1]$ objects out of $(20 + [6-1])$ objects.

---

In the 2nd line of reasoning, you suggest that you have $21$ objects, instead of $25$ objects.  However, the whole point of considering the selection of $n$ objects, $k$ at a time, without replacement is so that a bijection can be created between the set of all pertinent ordered $k$-tuples, and the set of all satisfying solutions to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 = 20.$$

The set of $k$-tuples in the first line of reasoning facilitates the necessary bijection.  The set of $k$-tuples in the second line of reasoning does not yield any corresponding bijection.

---

**Edit**
Reacting to the comment of Stinking Bishop following the posed question:

If the constraint is added that each of the $4$ interior variables must be $\geq 1$, the effect is that the equation requiring non-negative integer solutions is altered to

$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_6 = 16,$$

which would result in $~\displaystyle \binom{16 + [6-1]}{6-1} = \binom{21}{5}$ solutions.